# Terminating and Starting Data Connection on Windows Mobile 6.5 in C#?

Tags: c#, connection, compact-framework, terminate

I want to create an easy application for windows mobile devices, i have recently got a HTC HD2 and the connection is being eaten by the weather app, email accounts and windows live service :@

I am getting rather annoyed with this and well I have set myself a project to give myself a small piece of glory and create a working application that will Terminate an idle connection on my phone.

I am using C# and the latest WM6.5 sdk.

How do I access these controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [ConnectionManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdteam/archive/2004/09/15/230133.aspx) APIs to access device connections.  It will create them or hand existing connections to your application.  Closing a connection is actually very difficult to do (probably becasue it's not terribly nice to tear a connection out from under another running app) and has to be done via [P/Invoking to RAS](http://rascf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: AHHHH I seeee!! Thankyou! I guess this is the problem with stopping a connection on the phone because like i said like three apps are using this one conn and terminating all calls to it are near impossible for more than a couple of mins i guess :S 

Well im guna go on with this, thanks for your help. Ill maybe post back how it goes :)

Thanks again,

Ashh